# Cannot successfully have nested javascript .map's delivered a complexed output [{key, [{obj}, .. ]}, ..]

Tags: javascript

```
var serverdata = 
[{
    "Title": "FD",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 02:00:00"
},
{
    "Title": "FD",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 04:00:00"
},
{
    "Title": "FD",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 06:00:00"
},
{
    "Title": "LA",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 04:00:00"
},
{
    "Title": "LA",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 06:00:00"
},
{
    "Title": "LA",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 08:00:00"
},
{
    "Title": "TX",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 04:00:00"
},
{
    "Title": "TX",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 06:00:00"
},
{
    "Title": "TX",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 10:00:00"
}];

var _Graphs = _.groupBy( serverdata, "Title" );
_Graphs =  _Graphs.map( function(graph_i)  { 
    return({ key: graph_i[0].Title, values:
        graph_i.map( function ( graph_i_data ) { 
            return ( { label: graph_i_data.myX, value: graph_i_data.myVal } );
        }) });
} );
```

The above would fail at the first level of array.map:

```
_Graphs =  _Graphs.map( function(graph_i)
```

In the debugger, it shows the code bombed out at the first level of map not even reaching the inner map. It seems to me it is either my arguments weren't listed correctly or javascript's map fails to recognize that the outer level's object of arrays.  I use underscore for group.  Looks like I have to use underscore for map as well, and it works, just not map from java javascript!

Desired output :::>
[image: DesiredOutput]

Comment: Can you post desired output?

Comment: The result of `groupBy` is an object with no `map` function. Use `_.map` instead for object support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `_.groupBy`, it returns an object, where `map` works only with arrays. You can use `_.mapObject`.

```
_Graphs =  _.chain(serverdata).groupBy('Title').mapObject(function(val, key)  {   
    return({ key: key, values:
        val.map( function ( graph_i_data ) { 
            return ( { label: graph_i_data.myX, value: graph_i_data.myVal } );
        }) });
} ).values().value(); 
console.log(_Graphs);
```

**Demo:**

```js
var serverdata = 
[{
    "Title": "FD",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 02:00:00"
},
{
    "Title": "FD",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 04:00:00"
},
{
    "Title": "FD",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 06:00:00"
},
{
    "Title": "LA",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 04:00:00"
},
{
    "Title": "LA",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 06:00:00"
},
{
    "Title": "LA",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 08:00:00"
},
{
    "Title": "TX",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 04:00:00"
},
{
    "Title": "TX",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 06:00:00"
},
{
    "Title": "TX",
    "myVal": 0,
    "myX": "2016-07-10 10:00:00"
}];

_Graphs =  _.chain(serverdata).groupBy('Title').mapObject(function(val, key)  {   
    return({ key: key, values:
        val.map( function ( graph_i_data ) { 
            return ( { label: graph_i_data.myX, value: graph_i_data.myVal } );
        }) });
} ).values().value(); 
console.log(_Graphs);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, sir.  Also if I continued using underscore for map also, it also works. I have posted that version in the answer below.  But yours is good. I didn't even know mapObject exists. All I knew is the plain map could not swallow my object of arrays :O!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="script/underscore.js"></script>
```

Then in your mapping:

```
var _Graphs = _.groupBy( serverdata, "Title" );    
_Graphs =  _.map(_Graphs, function(graph_i)  { 
    return(/*= { key: "ANY", values: [] };*/{ key: graph_i[0].Title, values:
        _.map( graph_i, function ( graph_i_data) { 
            return ( { label: graph_i_data.myX, value: graph_i_data.myVal } );
        }) });
} );
```

One thing I could not understand is, if map in underscore works, javascript version should also work, but it didn't.  Don't quite get it.

Comment: Yes, sir!  They both yield the same result. I found it out after I gave up on javascript's map when you were finding me mapObject version.  Only difference is I do think the underscore/lodash map is easier to read.  Don't you think so?

Comment: Sure! Besides, underscore/lodash have many useful functional programming helpers.

Comment: love these meaningful names: lodash, fatArrow, ... so generic!